# Declare Jmeter variable from a property value

Tags: jmeter

How can I declare a variable name by using the value of a property?

For example, I have the property `propertyName` with the value `propertyValue`.  I want to declare a variable with the name `propertyValue`.

I've tried like `${${__P(variableName)}}` but such constructions doesnt work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may need to evaluate the property name, using the `${__V()}` [function](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/functions.html#__V).

Thus, you'd probably end up with something like $`{__V(${__P(propertyName)})}` which would only declare a variable with a null value.

**Basics on properties & command line:**

if you need to pass variables through the command line, properties are indeed the correct choice.

The flag to set a property is `-JpropertyName` The function to read a property is `${__P(propertyName)}`

For full details, see:

http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/JMeterFAQ#How_do_I_pass_parameters_into_my_Test_scripts.3F_I_want_to_be_able_to_use_the_same_script_to_test_with_different_numbers_of_threads_and_loops.2C_and_I_don.27t_want_to_have_to_change_the_script_each_time.

Comment: I want not to use property value itself, I want to use it's value as a variable name.

Comment: Interesting - what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: For instance, using groovy I put some value to a variable which name I want to compose of several part(prefix, name, postfix - all are variables or proerties). So after I run script, i have a new variable, with that name, and I wanna refer to it somewhere in a sampler.

Comment: @BlackGaff my value of property changed when converting to user defined variable keep on changing. ${__setProperty(updateid, 2534)}; when converting to variable it is changing to 2535.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Give up using properties files, try using [Variables From CSV](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/VariablesFromCSV) plugin. It is pretty simple and robust way to have variables loaded from file.

Answer (score 1):

Property files are great!!! For my requirement, I have created a simple config element for JMeter to read property files.

Please check here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element.